# iOS: UIColor is not honoring red, green, alpha, blue. shows other colors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I am new to `iOS` programming. I designed my `iOS` app screens using [sketch](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/)

The label that I designed in `Sketch` with color palette looks like
[image] [image]

However, when I do this in my code, I do

```
    self.yearHeaderLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:30];
    self.yearHeaderLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51 green:51 blue:51 alpha:100];
```

But when I run my application, I see
[image]

What is wrong with

```
self.yearHeaderLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51 green:51 blue:51 alpha:100];
```

Why is it not honoring the color?

Answer (score 2):

Small correction:

```
self.yearHeaderLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:51.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a minor change. `[UIColor:colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha]` takes *floats*, not *ints*, as arguments. Try the following instead:

```
self.yearHeaderLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51/255. green:51/255. blue:51/255. alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should place values like I have presented below otherwise it is not working properly

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:51.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

This means you need to normalize your values to have values in range <0,1>

Edit (according to some comments to that answer):

AppCode complains on that kind of passing values it feels satisfied with this version:

```
UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)(51.0/255.0) green:(CGFloat)(51.0/255.0) blue:(CGFloat)(51.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: I didn't down vote but I wanted to point out that you shouldn't use `f` to make `float` values. Under 64-bit builds, `CGFloat` will be a `double`.

Comment: @rmaddy, actually a good point, do you suggest casting on CGFloat

Comment: No, just use `51/255.0` and let the compiler cast as needed.

Comment: won't it complain as the the first value will be an int?

Comment: No, you can mix and match integral and floating point types and the compiler will cast as needed. Of course to get the right results from the division, at least one of the two values must be a floating point type.

Comment: checked, AppCode complains, see my edit